# Slimming down a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've had this program for a while now and it seems tedious to keep at it but I'm running my code against `pylint` for exercise purposes and I get the error **R0912: 69,0:process_ancestors: Too many branches (7/6)**. I was wondering if anyone would be able to assist me in slimming down this function as it appears to be in its simplest form to me..

```
def process_ancestors(relation_dict, name):
    '''Figures out who the ancestors are'''
    output_str = ''
    name_found = search_name(relation_dict, name)
    if not name_found: 
            output_str = "Unknown person"      
    else: 
        ancestor_list = []
        person = name
        while True: 
            person = find_parent(relation_dict, person)
            if person == None: 
                break
            else: 
                ancestor_list.append(person)
        if ancestor_list: 
            output_str = ", ".join(ancestor_list)
        else: 
            output_str = "No known ancestors"            

    return output_str
```

Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes were:

1. Returning imeidelty  (removed two branches)
2. Changed the while loop by setting the first iteration to happen before, eliminating the need to check for `None` inside the loop

Resulting in:

```
def process_ancestors(relation_dict, name):
    '''Figures out who the ancestors are'''
    name_found = search_name(relation_dict, name)
    if not name_found: 
            return "Unknown person"      
    ancestor_list = []
    person = name
    person = find_parent(relation_dict, person)
    while person is not None: 
        ancestor_list.append(person)
        person = find_parent(relation_dict, person)
    return ", ".join(ancestor_list) if ancestor_list else "No known ancestors"
```

Comment: No need for the ternary.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams how so?

Comment: The ternary makes things a little to terse. It's still a branch, but reduced redability.

Comment: Your code will raise a `UnboundLocalError` exception on the first reference to `person`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, had to be `name` not `person` on the first call. (or the equivalent)

Comment: You chopped out the `person = name` part but after I added that back in, it worked like a charm. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Androx yeah, I forgot to change first call to include `name` not `person` as I just copied and pasted the call from the body of the `while` loop. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Return early, that way you need far fewer `else:` branches:

```
def process_ancestors(relation_dict, name):
    '''Figures out who the ancestors are'''
    name_found = search_name(relation_dict, name)
    if not name_found: 
        return "Unknown person"      

    ancestor_list = []
    person = find_parent(relation_dict, name)
    while person is not None:
        ancestor_list.append(person)
        person = find_parent(relation_dict, person)

    if not ancestor_list: 
        return "No known ancestors"            
    return ", ".join(ancestor_list)
```

I've also removed the need to test for `person` being `None` in the `while` loop, removing another branch.

Comment: Your answer works but I now get **R0911: 68,0:process_ancestors: Too many return statements (3/2)** unfortunately ..

Comment: @Androx: Always switch that one off. `pylint` is *too* picky in places.

Comment: Yeah, my thoughts exactly. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

not sure it's shorter, but at least to me it's clearer:

```
def process_ancestors(relation_dict, name):
    '''Figures out who the ancestors are'''
    if not search_name(relation_dict, name):
        return "Unknown person"
    else:
        ancestor_list = list(ancestors(relation_dict, name))
        if not ancestor_list:
            return "Unknown parent"
        else:
            return ", ".join(ancestor_list)

def ancestors(relation_dict, person):
    '''A list of ancestors (excluding first person)'''
    while person:
        person = find_parent(relation_dict, person)
        if person: yield person
```

Comment: Why the `else` branches after returning in the `if`?

Comment: it's a style thing, and it depends who the code is for.  i just thought people would prefer it that way here.